# Is it bad form to ask for relocation compensation after having received contract?

Tags: human-resources, compensation

I remember taking on the phone to HR, they told me the general terms of the offer, then asked if I'd like to clarify anything. At the time, I couldn't think of anything particular.

Now that I've received the contract (haven't signed it yet), I've just realized it would be beneficial if I had a monthly stipend for relocation compensation.

Should I ask for it? I feel like it might be bad form because I should have asked about it before...then again, I'm super new to the workforce so I don't really know.

Comment: Did they say they'd give you compensation!?

Comment: Would you sign the contract if you dont get relocation help? Also usually is one single bonus to help you relocate. Not monthly stipend.

Answer (score 7):

You can *ask* for anything, but the best time to do this is **when you are negotiating the contract**.  Once you have signed it, you have agreed to the employment terms and really don't have a ton of leverage.

Since you haven't signed the contract yet, now is the time to negotiate!!

Comment: ah okay, I haven't signed the contract yet.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, but this is not without risk

1. Making a written offer, can be a fair bit of work. Often, it needs to be written up, reviewed by legal and HR, and then sent for approval up the food chain. If you change it, you have to do it all over again, which may annoy some people in HR or your hiring manager
2. You may create the impression of being a poor decision maker and being not good at "attention to detail"

This may or may not happen or matter in your case. Depends on the details